# How can i open a .FIN file in RStudio?

Tags: r, data-science

i'm working on a project on R, my problem is i don't know how can i open or load a .FIN file. I tried with

```
load("file.FIN")
```

And it doesn't work

Comment: Where did this FIN file come from? You can rename a file to have any extension you want and different programs may use the same extension for very different files. What's inside this file?

Comment: I don't see any R package in [this list](https://filext.com/file-extension/FIN).